What is my mistake in integrating $\int \frac{dx}{6 + \cot x}$?
I have solved this integral but I know there is an error, because when I check with Mathematica I see that the derivative of my answer does not give the original integrand of the problem.
$$\int \frac{dx}{6 + \cot x}$$
Realizamos la sustitución $t = \tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$, con lo cual tenemos:
$\cos x = \frac{1 - t^2}{1 + t^2} $, $ \sin x = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, and $dx=\frac{2}{t^2+1}dt $, por lo que tenemos $$\int \frac{dx}{6 + \cot x} =\int \frac{\frac{2}{1+t^2}}{6+\frac{1-t^2}{2t}}dt=\int\frac{4t}{(1+t^2)(-t^2+12t+6)}dt$$
$$=-4\int\frac{t}{(1+t^2)(t^2-12t-6)}dt=-4\int(\frac{At+B}{1+t^2}+\frac{Ct+D}{t^2-12t-6})dt$$
Entonces
$$t=(At+B)(t^2-12t-6)+(Ct+D)(1+t^2)=(A+C)t^3+(-12A+B+D)t^2+(-6A-12B+C)t-6B+D$$
Igualando,
\begin{cases}
   A + C = 0 \\
   -12 A + B + D = 0 \\
   -6 A - 12 B + C = 1 \\
   -6 B + D = 0
   \end{cases}
por lo que
\begin{cases}
   A = -\frac{7}{193} \\
   B = -\frac{12}{193} \\
   C = \frac{7}{193} \\
   D = -\frac{72}{193}
   \end{cases}
Sustituyendo los valores en el integrando,
$$-4\int(\frac{At+B}{1+t^2}+\frac{Ct+D}{t^2-12t-6})dt=-4\int(\frac{\frac{-7t}{193}-\frac{12}{193}}{1+t^2}+\frac{\frac{7}{193}-\frac{72}{193}}{t^2-12t-6})$$
$$=-4\int-\frac{1}{193}(\frac{7t+12}{1+t^2})dt-4\int\frac{1}{193}(\frac{7t-72}{t^2-12t-6})dt$$
$$=\color{green}{\frac{4}{193}}\color{blue}{\int\frac{7t+12}{1+t^2}dt}-\color{green}{\frac{4}{193}}\color{blue}{\int\frac{7t-72}{t^2-12t-6}dt}$$
Ahora trabajamos con las integrales por separado.
Por un lado tenemos
$$\color{blue}{\int\frac{7t+12}{1+t^2}dt}=\frac{7}{2}\int\frac{2t}{1+t^2}dt+12\int\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt=\frac{7}{2}\ln(1+t^2)+12\arctan(t)+k_1$$
Por otro lado,
$$\color{blue}{\int\frac{7t-72}{t^2-12t-6}dt}=\int\frac{7t-72}{t^2-12t+36-42}dt=\int\frac{7t-72}{(t-6)^2-\sqrt{42}^2}dt$$
Cambiando de variable $\sqrt{42}u=t-6\rightarrow \sqrt{42}du=dt$,
$$=\int\frac{7t-72}{(t-6)^2-\sqrt{42}^2}dt=\int\frac{[7(\sqrt{42}+6)-72]\sqrt{42}}{(\sqrt{42}u)^2-\sqrt{42}^2}du=\int\frac{(7\sqrt{42}u-30)\sqrt{42}}{\sqrt{42}^2(u^2-1)}du$$
$$=\int\frac{7(42)u}{42(u^2-1)}du-\frac{30\sqrt{42}}{42}\int\frac{1}{u^2-1}du=\frac{7}{2}\int\frac{2u}{u^2-1}du+\frac{30}{\sqrt{42}}\int\frac{1}{1-u^2}du$$
$$=\frac{7}{2}\operatorname{ln}\vert u^2-1 \vert + \frac{30}{\sqrt{42}}\operatorname{arctanh}u+k_2=\frac{7}{2}\operatorname{ln} \vert (\frac{t-6}{\sqrt{42}})^2-1 \vert +\frac{30}{\sqrt{42}}\operatorname{arctanh{}\frac{t-6}{\sqrt{42}}}+k_2$$
$$=\frac{7}{2}\operatorname{ln} \vert t^2-12t-6 \vert +\frac{30}{\sqrt{42}}\operatorname{arctanh\frac{t-6}{\sqrt{42}}}+k_2$$
Volviendo a la integral de arriba:
$$=\color{green}{\frac{4}{193}}(\color{blue}{\frac{7}{2}\ln(1+t^2)+12\arctan(t)+k_1})-\color{green}{\frac{4}{193}}(\color{blue}{\frac{7}{2}\operatorname{ln} \vert t^2-12t-6 \vert +\frac{30}{\sqrt{42}}\operatorname{arctanh\frac{t-6}{\sqrt{42}}}+k_2})$$
Finalmente, como $t=\tan(\frac{x}{2})$, nos queda:
$$\int \frac{dx}{6 + \cot x} = \frac{4}{193}[\frac{7}{2}\ln(1 + \tan^2(x/2))+12\arctan(\tan(x/2))] - \frac{4}{193}[\frac{7}{2}\operatorname{ln} \vert \tan^2(x/2)-12\tan(x/2)-6 \vert +\frac{30}{\sqrt{42}}\operatorname{arctanh(\frac{\tan(x/2)-6}{\sqrt{42}}})]+k$$
But


Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

In the first line, after you applied the substitution of $\tan\frac{x}{2}$, your integral is wrong, $\int\frac{4t}{(1+t^2)(-t^2+12t+6)}dt$ is wrong, $\int\frac{4t}{(1+t^2)(-t^2+12t+1)}dt$ is correct
Here's a simple alternate approach (to refer to):
$$I=\int\frac{1}{6+\cot x}\,dx$$
$$I=\int\frac{\tan x}{6\tan x +1}\,dx$$
$$\tan x = t \implies \sec^2 x \,dx=dt$$
$$I=\int\frac{t}{(6t +1)(t^2+1)}\,dt$$
Performing partial fractions;
$$\frac{t}{(6t +1)(t^2+1)}=\frac{a}{6t+1}+\frac{bt+c}{t^2+1}\implies a=\frac{-6}{37}, b=\frac{1}{37}, c=\frac{6}{37}$$
$$I=\frac{1}{37}\left(\int\frac{t+6}{(t^2+1)}\,dt-\int\frac{6}{6t+1}\,dt\right)$$
The above integrals, can be further split and easily evaluated against standard integrals;
This approach gives the following closed form:
$$I=\frac{1}{74}\left[ln\left(\frac{\sec^2 x}{(6\tan x+1)^2}\right)+12x\right]+C$$

Tangent-half-angle substitution is rather clumsy. It is easier to evaluate the integral by splitting
$$
\sin x=\frac{6}{37}(6 \sin x+\cos x)-\frac{1}{37}(6 \cos x-\sin x)
$$
as
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int \frac{d x}{6+\cot x} 
& =\int \frac{\sin x}{6 \sin x+\cos x} d x \\
& =\int \frac{\frac{6}{37}(6 \sin x+\cos x)-\frac{1}{37}(6 \cos x-\sin x)}{6 \sin x+\cos x} d x \\
& =\frac{6}{37} x-\frac{1}{37} \int \frac{d(6 \sin x+\cos x)}{6 \sin x+\cos x} \\
& =\frac{6}{37} x-\frac{1}{37} \ln |6 \sin x+\cos x|+C \\
&= \frac{1}{37}\left[\ln \left|\frac{\sec x}{6 \tan x+1}\right|+6 x\right]+C
\end{aligned}
$$
which matches the answer provided by @whatamidoing.
